# Праздничный вопрос: что означает Даздрасен?

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Правда ли, что Даздрасен — имя, смысл которого: "Да здравствует седьмое ноября!"?

Разрешено ли давать такое имя в Российской Федерации и других странах бывшего СССР?

Answer (score 2):

[Федеральный закон от 1 мая 2017 года № 94-ФЗ "О внесении изменений в статью 58 Семейного кодекса Российской Федерации и статью 18 Федерального закона «Об актах гражданского состояния»"]

**Запрещается** использовать имена, которые содержат:
бранные слова;
указания на титулы, должности, ранги;
числительные символы;
знаки, не являющиеся буквенными, кроме знака «дефис»;
цифры;
буквенно-цифровые обозначения.

Если у отца и матери ребенка разные фамилии, ребенку может быть присвоена одна из них либо двойная фамилия. Для этого необходимо согласие двух родителей.
Если присваивается двойная фамилия, она может состоять максимум из двух слов, разделенных знаком «дефис». У полнородных сестер и братьев с двойной фамилией не может быть изменена последовательность присоединения фамилий матери и отца.

**Получается, что всё остальное — разрешено.**
Так что вполне возможно, что [**Даздрасен**](http://imenana.ru/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B8/) — "Да здравствует седьмое ноября!".

Есть похожие имена:
Ватерпежекосма — Валентина Терешкова — первая женщина-космонавт;
**Даздрасмыгда** — Да здравствует смычка города и деревни;
**Даздраперма** — Да здравствует первое мая;
Пофистал — Победитель фашизма Иосиф Сталин;
Кукуцаполь — Кукуруза царица полей;
Пятвчет — Пятилетку в четыре года;
Урювкос — Ура, Юра в космосе;
Перкосрак — Первая космическая ракета.
[**Необычные имена**](http://lifeglobe.net/entry/4105)

В Эстонии приблизительно такие же правила для *новых* имен. Ограничение: их (как и фамилий) не может быть больше трех.
Фамилии обычно пишутся через дефис (Штейнберг-Салтыкова; Линдблом-Линдблюм), для имен наличие дефиса не обязательно (Антон Альберт; Мария Элизабет; Сандра Александра; Триину-Теэле; Катарина-Беата).

Редкие имена, встреченные мною в Эстонии в последнее время: женские — Архелая, Синильга, мужские — Сильвестр, Ксаверий.

Answer (score 1):

В России разрешено любое цензурное имя без цифр и нечитаемых графических знаков. В других странах бывшего СССР по-разному. Где-то без проблем, а где-то, например, в Таджикистане можно называть ребёнка только местным именем.
Помимо того, имя не входит в Святцы, поэтому крестить будут под другим.